# Puppet noob, stuck on the same error for hours

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm trying to setup a puppet master with hiera.

When I try "puppet agent --test" on the mongo node I get this error.

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find default node or by name with 'mongo.example.com, mongo.example, mongo' on node mongo.example.com
>   Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>   Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

I have:

/etc/puppet/hieradata/production/common.yaml
/etc/puppet/hieradata/production/mongo.example.com.yaml

this is my hiera.yaml

```
---

:backends:
  - yaml

:hierarchy:
  - "%{::fqdn}"
  - common

:yaml:
   :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata/%{environment}/
```

Comment: // , Please, show the research you have gone through so far, already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define a node in `$PUPPETDIR/manifests/site.pp` (or `node.pp`, as this is usually imported from `site.pp` and is  meant to keep node defs).

Comment: This. Although you should no longer [import](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_import.html#deprecation-notice) manifest files.